# How to filter an array of Objects based on the values that are already taken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that is like:

```
const FirstAidTypeSource = [
  { Name: "First Aid", Value: "First Aid" },
  { Name: "Senior First Aid", Value: "Senior First Aid" },
  { Name: "Anaphylaxis Certificate", Value: "Anaphylaxis Certificate" },
  { Name: "Asthma Certificate", Value: "Asthma Certificate" }
];
```

and every time I use one of them I want it to be removed from the list, for example, if I create the first certificate and select "First Aid" then when I create the second certificate I don't want "First Aid" again in the list and it shouldn't be selectable, even though I found another way to do it which is working ok, but when I delete one certificate everything will mess up, for example, if I add 3 certificates and choose "First Aid" for the first one and "Senior First Aid" for the second one and so on, and then if I want to delete the first one then even though I deleted the first one which is "First Aid" and should be deleted but it is still there and also the "Add Certificate" button will disappear.
please refer to the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-water-6ft412?file=/src/App.js) for details

any help is appreciated in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's because the button renders if `index + 1 === formRef.current`, but `formRef.current` isn't being updated when you delete a certificate.

So what I did was change `formRef` from a reference to a state, after making sure it's not being used a reference elsewhere. Then set up an effect hook that updates `formRef` based on the length of `firstAids` each time `firstAids` updates.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    setFormRef(firstAids.length)
  }, [firstAids])
```

By having it as a state, the component will re-render after it's updated, and properly render the button.

Try it out:

[image: Edit sweet-haslett-guxkjl]

Comment: thanks @Brother58697 but it doesn't work, still if you delete certificate 1 for example then certificate 2 will move to certificate 1

Comment: I;ve been looking at it for some time and I think the issue is with how you're setting the new certificates array at line 126, but I'm not 100% sure. I really want to help you more, but I'm sorry because I can't spend more time on this. The solution feels so close so good luck!

Comment: [Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-herschel-c74css?file=/src/App.js) another approach to the overall app, maybe it can help give some inspiration and new ideas.